# VBA in Excel - open .dat file

Tags: excel, vba

I have .dat file from economic system. In this file is table with more columns and rows. I need to update this file by using excel.
I find some code with declared: Dim sFile as New BFTable, but This macro after run, return me error with register class. Can you help me with this problem?
Is there some way, how to open this file and in Excel edit and then update to file? I can provide the file.

```
Sub Makro1()

  Dim tAgenda As New BFTable
  
  tAgenda.Open (List1.Cells(2, 2).Value)
  
  Do While Not tAgenda.EOF
   If tAgenda.Value("Variable") = "Name" Then
     List1.Cells(1, 1).Value = tAgenda.Value("Value")
     Exit Do
   End If
   tAgenda.Next
  Loop
  
  tAgenda.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're having problems with some code, then you need to *post the code* and explain the specific error you're getting, and on which line.  A few sample lines from your dataset (redacted as necessary) would also be useful.  No-one can help you by just guessing what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert this code.

Comment: You can Edit your question if you need to add code or other information. More than one line of code in comments is not easy to follow.  You should also include the link to the original code you're basing this on - there is no `BFTable` type in Excel VBA for example.

Comment: Done. Sorry for bad question..

Comment: Excel VBA does not have a `BFTable` type, so you need to tell us what that is....

Answer (score 0):

If the error you're getting is "User-defined type not defined", that means that VBA does not recognize BFTable as a data type. When it doesn't know the data type, it assumes it's a custom type. It's actually one of three things:

1. You misspelled the data type. Like `Dim x As Stirng` - it would know String, but not the misspelled word.
2. You need to add a library. If you type `Dim x As Dictionary` you get that error unless you go to Tools - References and the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library that defines what a Dictionary is. So if BFTable comes from some third part library, you'll need to get it and add a reference to it.
3. Or the code uses a custom class module that you don't have in your code. If the original code has a custom class module named BFTable, you'll need to add that module to your code.